# Saving a photo attached in text message

Tags: photos, mms, file-management, attachments

I have a Galaxy S2, running Android 4.0.3

I can open a photo attached to a text message. How can I save the photo (not the message)?

Comment: Have you tried a long-press?

Answer (score 5):

When in the message window, "long press" the image (hold your finger down on the image for a second or two) and a menu should pop up giving you the option to download or save the attachment.

When you go to your gallery you'll usually see attachments you've downloaded in a folder called "Downloads" or "Messaging."

Answer (score 2):

On my android 4.4.2 tablet running the app "messaging 4.40.150" do a long hold on the message body not the photo.  It opens a dialogue which allows saving the attachment.  It was easy after that.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Galaxy S4 running Android 4.2.2

1. In Messaging in the Message I have been sent a photo.. underneath it says MMS
2. I tap the photo and it goes fullscreen
3. I tap the (anachronistic floppy disk) save icon
4. I can rename it
5. I hit OK and it responds with: Attachment copied to device storage
6. It is now saved to:

> Internal Storage/Download

- I use Dropbox to grab it from there
- It does not appear in my Gallery :(

If I accidentally long-press I choose *Save Attachment* for the same thing

Answer (score 0):

On my phone, running CyanogenMod 12.1, I wasn't asked where to put the file or what to name it. It automatically went to the Downloads folder. In there, it had a cryptic file name: `cid:262`. I just renamed it to whatever I wanted + `.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Long press the message (not the image or video)
2. A pop-up window will appear, select `save attachments`
3. Files are saved to my `Downloads` directory

Steps taken from a Droid Turbo